# xml parsing is done but the values are not added to the array in swift

Tags: swift

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<account>
  <username>dedehakan</username>
  <avatar>http://www.somewebsite.com/empty.png</avatar>
  <email>test@gmail.com</email>
  <points>450</points>
  <type>premium</type>
  <expiration>666666</expiration>
  <expiration-txt>17/12/2014 20:37:35</expiration-txt>
  <premium-left>-614239</premium-left>
</account>
```

i want to parse this with nsxmlparser. I get parsing done correctly how ever didnt get any values.
here what i try:

```
var mydata:NSData = resp.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!
var xmlParser = NSXMLParser(data: mydata)
xmlParser.delegate = self
xmlParser.parse()
```

resp is string and the value of resp is xml text.

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: NSDictionary!) {
    println(elementName)
    println(attributeDict)
}
```

The output is:

```
account
nil
username
nil
avatar
nil
email
nil
....
```

The question is how i get the values in xml string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the data in your XML document does *not* come from attributes; it comes from the textual content of the tag itself. That is why you get all these `nil`s when you print `attributeDict`.

To fix this, you need to do these four things:

- Add an instance variables `lastTag:String?` and `tagContent:String?` to your parser delegate class
- Set `lastTag` to `elementName` in the `didStartElement` function
- Provide an implementation of the `foundCharacters` function that *appends* characters to `tagContent` string
- Provide an implementation of `didEndElement` function which uses the tag and the content in whatever way that you need, and then sets them both to `nil`.

To make a long story short, you need to wait until the content of the tag has become available until you reach the end tag, at which point you could "harvest" the content from instance variables.

Comment: yeah i see my problem... Thanks for the hint